# ionic 1 app white screen in IOS 10.2, but everything is OK in other versions of IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

[image: system env config]

[image: device version]

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="default-src 
    gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *"
>
```

Someone fix this issue by change the 'gap' value of meta tag , but this is not effect in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' gap: ; img-src * 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Comment: I tied this,but still white screen